# Mysql orderBy count of field name from another table

Tags: php, mysql

This is the page URL 
http://domain.com/testphp?id=1&mview=4

The choices are displayed from the table named
**je_add_choice** and it contains the field names

1. choice_id
2. poll_id
3. choice_creator_id
4. choice_name
5. choice_image
6. description
7. Choicecreationtime

It displays the choices with their votes for the particular poll, what i want to do is, I have to display the choices orderby no of votes. But the problem is, The vote count for the choices are from another table named **je_user_vote**
and it contains the fields

1. user_id
2. Poll_id
3. choice_id
4. vote_id (primary key)
5. datetime_voted
6. usertype

In the poll page i used the query

```
select * from je_addchoice where poll_id='$poll_id'
```

In this query the $pollid variable is get from the url $_GET['id']

I want to rewrite the query as

```
select * from je_addchoice where poll_id='$poll_id' // append the code order by count(fieldname) from je_user_vote table.
```

I already used

```
SELECT *, (
            SELECT count(*) 
            FROM je_uservote T2 
            WHERE T2.pollid=T1.pollID 
            AND T2.choiceid=T1.choiceID) AS votes
FROM je_addchoice T1
ORDER BY votes
```

But it shows the blank page. Anybody can help me for solve this problem. Thanks in advance for reading this and help me to solve

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result?

Comment: The below result works for me, but how to give the where condition i dont know. It displays all the poll choices. I need the same query with where condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is left join and aggregate function to calculate the vote. Here query you can try (untested):

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_votes, t1.* 
FROM je_add_choice t1
LEFT JOIN je_user_vote t2
    ON t1.choice_id=t2.choice_id
    AND t1.poll_id=t2.Poll_id
WHERE t1.poll_id = " . $poll_id . "
GROUP BY t1.choice_id
ORDER BY 1 ASC"
```

Comment: yes it displays all the poll choices, but i have the condition where t1.poll_id = $poll_id. what i have to do for that

Comment: You can simply add it in WHERE clause. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.choice_id) AS total_votes, t1.* 
    FROM je_addchoice t1
    LEFT JOIN je_user_vote t2
        ON t1.choice_id=t2.choice_id
        AND t1.poll_id=t2.Poll_id
    WHERE t1.poll_id = " . $poll_id . "    
    GROUP BY t1.choice_id
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

This is the answer for my question. I just take coding from subred's answer and modify the names as required in the page and then i got results. Now is working fine

http://www.domain.com/projects/je/pollpage.php?id=2&mview=4

This is the URL in which the choice are now displayed in order of high count votes to low count votes

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.choice_id) AS total_votes, t1.* 
    FROM je_addchoice t1
    LEFT JOIN je_user_vote t2
        ON t1.choice_id=t2.choice_id
        AND t1.poll_id=t2.Poll_id
    WHERE t1.poll_id = " . variable_name . "    
    GROUP BY t1.choice_id
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Hope this helps.